# Clicking a bootstrap dropdown item with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bootstrap-4, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select an item from a bootstrap dropdown with selenium. I can click the dropdown itself and get the options shown, but I can't click any option.

I tried different things but I'm getting:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

This is the line that I need to fix:

```
option = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//li[text()='Element'"))
option.click()
```

I also tried using this code with the same error:

```
options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("//ul[contains(@class,'a-list')]/a"))
for option in options:
optionText = option.text()
if optionText == ('Element'):
    option.click()
    break
```

I also tried using these codes with different xpath in case that was the mistake, but keep getting the same error.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I should have used another page as an example. Like this one
https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap4/demo.php?ex=79.0_1
If I wanted to click on "CSS" it might be something like this?:
options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH("//ul[contains(@class,'dropdown-menu')]/a"))
for option in options:
optionText = option.text()
if optionText == ('CSS'):
    option.click()
    break

Answer (score 1):

You can open the CSS option on `https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap4/demo.php?ex=79.0_1` page with simple 2 clicks:

1. Click the drop down button.
2. Click the desired option.
   Of cause you need to wait for these elements clickability before performing the clicks, but this can be achieved with `WebDriverWait` expected conditions.
   The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = "https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap4/demo.php?ex=79.0_1"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='css']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different typos with your code:

- `find_element()` should take two arguments (not one), the first is the selector type such as `By.XPATH`, which translates to `"xpath"`. The second argument should be a selector of that type.
- `By.XPATH` is a string, not a method (you used it like a mathod).
- Your first selector was missing a closing bracket, `]`.

Try this, which fixes your issues:

```py
option = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Element']")
option.click()
```